# my search input doesn't work when loaded into bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, json

I have search input which opens up a modal and displays delivery addresses when a user has entered a postcode.

When the modal opens, the information displays fine but when the user enters a postcode into the search input which is now in the modal - the results do not refresh.

The input field is a live search which is just a copy of the first search the user interacts with.

Below is my HTML

First search bar

```
                        <div class="col-12 click-collect--container px-0">
                                <form>
                                <label for="postcode" class="d-inline-block w-100">Find your nearest pick up point</label>
                                    <div>
                                    <input class="form-control float-left" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search by postcode" type="text">
                                    <input class="btnpostcode btn btn-primary" data-target="#exampleModalLive" data-toggle="modal" id="Btn_Search" name="BtnPostCode" value="Search >">
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                        </div>
```

This is the HTML for the modal with the search input

```
<div class="modal" id="exampleModalLive" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Click and Collect</h5><button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                    <div id="count"></div>
                                                                <div class="col-12 click-collect--container px-0">
                                <form>
                                <label for="postcode" class="d-inline-block w-100">Find your nearest pick up point</label>
                                    <div>
                                    <input class="form-control float-left" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search by postcode" type="text">
                                    <input class="btnpostcode btn btn-primary" id="Btn_Search" name="BtnPostCode" value="Search >">
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group mt-3" id="result"></ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="d-inline-block w-100">
                        <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:300px;"></div>
                            <ul class="list-group" id="lat-long"></ul>
                        </div>
                        <Div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <ul class="list-group" id="address-container"></ul>
                            <ul class="list-group" id="opening-times"></ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div id="del-lists-wrapper"> </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery

```
    $('#search').blur(function() {
        $('#result').html('');
        $('#lat-long').html('');
        $('#opening-times').html('');
        $('#del-lists-wrapper').html('');
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/m0a3m', function(data) {
            //console.log('json')
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {

                if (value.address.postcode.search(expression) != -1) {
                //console.log(value)
                    //COURIER ADDRESS DETAILS
                    $('#result').append('<li data-contentid='+ key +' class="list-group-item courier"><div class="c-name font-weight-bold"> ' + value.name + ' </div><div class="address"> ' + value.address.name + ',' + value.address.line1 + ',' + value.address.town + ',' + value.address.county + ',' + value.address.postcode + '</div></li>');
                    //LAT AND LONG
                    var mapProp= {
                        center:new google.maps.LatLng(value.location.latitude,value.location.longitude),
                        zoom:5,
                        };
                    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

                    //OPENING TIMES
                    $('#opening-times').append('<li id=open-times-'+ key +'  class="list-group-item op-times"><div class="c-name font-weight-bold"> Opening Times </div><div class="">Mon ' + value.opening_times.Mon + ' </div><div class="">Tues ' + value.opening_times.Tues + ' </div><div class="">Wed ' + value.opening_times.Wed + ' </div><div class="">Thurs ' + value.opening_times.Thurs + ' </div><div class="">Fri ' + value.opening_times.Fri + ' </div><div class="">Sat ' + value.opening_times.Sat + ' </div><div class="">Sun ' + value.opening_times.Sun + ' </div></li>');
            // ARRAY DELIVERY OPTIONS
            var ul = $('<ul id=del-add-'+ key +' class="del-options"></ul>');
            $.each(value.delivery_options, function(key, val) {
                ul.append('<li del-id=' + key + '  class="list-group-item"><div class="c-name font-weight-bold"> ' + val.name + ' </div><div> ' + val.description + ' </div><div class="c-price font-weight-bold"> ' + val.price + ' </div><div class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3"><a>Select ></a></div></li>');
            });
            ul.appendTo('#del-lists-wrapper');

                    //COURIER ADDRESS FOR OTHER CONTAINER
                    $('#address-container').append('<li id=cour-add-'+ key +'  class="list-group-item alt-address"><div class="c-name font-weight-bold"> ' + value.name + ' </div><div class="d-inline-block w-100"> ' + value.address.name + ' </div><div class="d-inline-block w-100"> ' + value.address.line1 + ' </div><div class="d-inline-block w-100"> ' + value.address.town + '</div><div class="d-inline-block w-100"> ' + value.address.county + ' </div><div class="d-inline-block w-100"> ' + value.address.postcode + '</div></li>');
                }
            });

        });


    });
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your listener is looking for the first instance of the id named search. You need to name the second one something like like "modal-search" and include that in your "search" event listener.

```
$('#serach', '#modal-search')
```

Either that or make a class="search" and then listen for it via `$('.search')` rather than `$('#search')`

Comment: The answer spots the error behind OPs problem, but you should really put alot more emphasis on *duplicate id values being illegal*.

Comment: @Danzel91 - Are you sure you still don't have more than one input with id="search"?

Comment: @Difster I don't. I only have the first search input with an id="search". The other search I changed the ID name and followed your instructions but yet the results list doesn't refresh

Comment: @Difster It works If i copy the whole search function and rename the ID to modal-search but when I include the modal search id alongside the search id in the same function - it doesn't :/

Comment: @Danzel91 - It looks like you have a bunch of other IDs in there too. Each ID has to be unique. If you have more than one element with the same ID name, it's going to stop at the first one it comes across.